# Computing the efficiency of a heat engine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

With the heat engine

[image]

we have an ideal gas working the substance.  I want to show that the efficiency of this heat engine is

$$\eta = 1 - \frac{1}{\gamma}\frac{\bigg(\frac{V_3}{V_1}\bigg)^\gamma - \bigg(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\bigg)^\gamma}{\bigg(\frac{V_3}{V_1} - \frac{V_2}{V_1}\bigg)} $$

where $\gamma = \dfrac{C_p}{C_v}$ is the adiabetic index.

So we have that $Q_1$ enters during the expansion $B \to C$ and $Q_2$ leaves during the compression $D \to A$.  Therefore,

$$\eta = \frac{Q_1 - Q_2}{Q_1} = 1 - \frac{Q_2}{Q_1}$$

I'm kind of stuck at this point.  Any further help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Now you just need to compute $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ in terms of state variables.

Let's consider $Q_1=Q_{CB}$.  The First Law of Thermodynamics tells us that for the process $B\to C$ we have
\begin{align}
  E_{CB} = Q_{CB} - W_{CB}
\end{align}
Since the pressure is a constant, say $P_2$, the work done is
\begin{align}
  W_{CB} = \int_{V_2}^{V_3}P\, dV = P_2(V_3-V_2).
\end{align}
On the other hand, the change in internal energy is
\begin{align}
   E_{CB} = C_V(T_3-T_2)
\end{align}
so from the First Law, we get
\begin{align}
  Q_1 = C_V(T_3-T_2) + P_2(V_3-V_2)
\end{align}
Now, you do an analogous thing to determine $Q_2$ in terms of state variables, and do some simplifications using, among other things, the ideal gas law.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble getting it into the required format.  For instance how does $T_4$ just go away?

Comment: @Jon It can be eliminated in favor of $T_3, V_3$, and $V_1$ since $TV^{\gamma-1}$ is constant for an adiabatic process.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Also for $Q_2$, $E_{AD}$ is computed the same way, but how do I compute $W_{AD}$?

Comment: @Jon Since $dV=0$ along that path, the work done is zero.

Comment: That's what I suspected.  It just didn't seem intuitive (physically)

Comment: @Jon Think of a gas trapped in a rigid, metal container, and imagine slowly cooling the gas down by putting the container in contact with something cold.  The pressure of the gas will decrease, but its not doing work on anything.